# Runtime Exception unable to start activity

Tags: android

can someone help me with error?
How to solve this exection?

> Unable to start activity
>   "ComponentInfo{com.example.name.myApp/com.example.dima.myApp.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error
>   inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout"

This is my activity_main:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:background="@drawable/city">

    <View
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle_background"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.511"
            android:id="@+id/view" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:ems="10"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:textColorHint="#000000"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle_email"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.392" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/view" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:ems="10"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:textColorHint="#000000"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle_email"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.677" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/email" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/email"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/email"/>
    <Button
            android:text="Sign in"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/signIn"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view" android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.25"
            android:layout_below="@+id/password" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="@string/newAccount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/newAccount" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/signIn"
            android:textSize="12sp" android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:layout_below="@+id/signIn" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginTop="11dp"/>
    <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/account"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView" android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/email" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/email"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/email"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/email" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/email"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/email" android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>
    <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/lock"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/password" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/password"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/password"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/password"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I just want to see my desigh on phone, how it will look like.
My MainActivity does not have any action:

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRJDl.png

Comment: add your java and xml code.

Comment: Add your layout xml here.

Comment: You have problems with  your MainActivity's xml. Please show your layout xml here.

Comment: TruongHieu I have added

Comment: Is this the whole log?

Comment: I've added a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you must remove all the attributes from your views that refer to a constraint layout because you're using a relative layout.  
Your relative layout cannot be inflated and since it contains all the common attributes, the problem should be here:

```
android:background="@drawable/city"
```

remove this line and try again

Comment: Thanks, I`ve deleted "android:background="@drawable/city"".

Comment: Try with a different smaller drawable

Answer (score 0):

remove all the properties start with `app:` because it belongs to `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: I have done it. But it did not help((

Answer (score 0):

May your xml file version is limited...

[image]

Comment: I'm new to Android development. Can you tell me what should I do?

Comment: @Boar in android studio see **activity_main.xml** in the drawable if the xml show version code like (v21) or other version then, make new **activity_main.xml** and copy and past all code to it....